# How can display a menu item border even if the document is reloading?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this sample:

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/dhMSN/1/)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a>
    <li><a href="#" title="Sub-Menu Item 1">Link2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub-Sub-Menu Item 1">Home Link 1 Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub-Sub-Menu Item 2">Home Link 1 Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub-Sub-Menu Item 3">Home Link 1 Link 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
ul{
    list-style-type:none;
}

.menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}
.menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.active{
    border-left:2px solid red;
}
```

**CODE JS:**

```
    $('.menu li ').click(function(){
       $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
```

My problem is following

If a user click for example on the element 4 and page reload,element 4 not have `border-left`

In the above example this works because everything is dinamic..dar imagine what would happen when opening a new HTML page...then the menu item that was clicked not have border-left.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer may depend on the technology you are using. If you can alter the rendered HTML, you could implement server-side a way to have the page loaded with the active class set on the desired item. If you want to keep with the static HTML, then you could work with something like `mypage.html#item4` and use javascript to get the selected item upon page load and apply the class to the desired item.

Answer (score 0):

You cant show a menu bar or infact anything if the whole page is getting reloaded. But you can use AJAX calls for it. It will reload or update only a part of the page so that the menu remains as it is.

Comment: so complicated is it?
I believe it can solve and simpler